# How to connect a multi page web app to graphql?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, express-graphql

I have a backend graphql server in express, node. I have a react Single Page Application(SPA) admin web app that communicates to graphql via Apollo. I need a a Multi Page Application (MPA) Content Management Site (CMS) for general internet user to consume.

The problem is that how to connect MPA to graphql. How should I get data from graphql at the backend and generate pages using the data in the backend and send pages to a user?

Comment: How you do SSR depends on the front-end framework and GraphQL client you're using. For example: [how this is done with react-apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/performance/server-side-rendering/). Even with that information, though, this question is a bit too broad for SO.